# Multiple firewalls Symfony security

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I'm getting an error when using 2 firewalls for my Symfony app. I have a firewall for regular members and another for vendors.

The error is "Unable to find the controller for path "/vendor/login-check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?"

The member_secured_area works perfectly fine when I hit any of the login and logout routes, but it does not work for the vendor_secured_area routes.

When I go to the /vendor/dashboard route it redirects me to /vendor/login but posting to the /vendor/login-check fails with the above error.

Thanks

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        vendor_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/vendor/dashboard
            provider: member
            anonymous: false
            form_login:
                login_path: vendor-login
                check_path: vendor-login-check
            logout:
                path: vendor-logout
                target: /
        member_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: member
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: member-login
                check_path: member-login-check
                default_target_path: home
                success_handler: security.authentication_handler
                failure_handler: security.authentication_handler
            logout:
                path: member-logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                key: "%secret_key%"
                lifetime: 2592000
                path: /
                domain: ~
    access_control:
        member_access:
            path: ^/member/dashboard
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
#        vendor_access:
#            path: ^/vendor/dashboard
#            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
```

Comment: Do you have a route that responds to `/vendor/login-check` URL ? If you run `app/console router:debug | grep login` does it show up ?

Comment: @Hpatoio Yes it does. I know it works because I swapped the 2 check routes and it works with the members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. My login, logout and check paths were not behind the firewall.

I had to allow anonymous to my vendor secure area to allow the login page to be accessed, then using the access control to require a role.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    vendor_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/vendor/dashboard
        provider: member
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: vendor-login
            check_path: vendor-login-check
            default_target_path: vendor-dashboard-index
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path: vendor-logout
            target: /
    member_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: member
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: member-login
            check_path: member-login-check
            default_target_path: home
            success_handler: security.authentication_handler
            failure_handler: security.authentication_handler
        logout:
            path: member-logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret_key%"
            lifetime: 2592000
            path: /
            domain: ~
access_control:
    - { path: ^/member/dashboard, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: ^/vendor/dashboard/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/vendor/dashboard, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```